# Storing and Viewing Base64 Image in S3

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular6

I am storing an image to S3 like below:

```
const params = {
  Bucket: "xyz-bucket",
  Key: this.folder + this.filename,
  Body: file,
  ACL: "public-read",
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  ContentType: 'image/jpg'
};
```

it stores successfully in S3 as: https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xyz-bucket/1552861956582_0djO8.jpg

but when I try to view it, I see:
[image: image when viewed directly using s3 url on browser]

When I download the file and open in text editor I see, depending on what I store. I tried both ways and I dont see the image:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAA...
```

OR

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0...
```

Now, the question is where am I wrong? the way I save the file or they way I am trying to view it.

## UPDATED

```
openGallery() {
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  correctOrientation: true,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
};
this.camera
  .getPicture(options)
  .then(data_uri => {
    this.upload(data_uri);
  }, err => console.log(err));
}

upload(file: any) {
  this.uploadService.uploadfile(file);
}
```

## upload.service.ts

```
uploadfile(file) {
const bucket = new S3({
  accessKeyId: "****",
  secretAccessKey: "*******",
  region: "***"
});

var epoch_timestamp = new Date().getTime();
this.filename = epoch_timestamp + "_" + this.randomStringGenerator() + ".jpg";
const params = {
  Bucket: "xyz-bucket",
  Key: this.folder + this.filename,
  Body: file,
  ACL: "public-read",
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  ContentType: 'image/jpg'
};

bucket.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("There was an error uploading your file: ", err);
    return false;
  }

  console.log("Successfully uploaded file.", data);
  return true;
});

randomStringGenerator(length = 5) {
var text = "";
var possible =
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

return text;
```

}

Comment: can you please write down the image upload code so we can find what want wrong because when you are directly open the image from url you are not able to see the image so i guess something is wrong with the image conversion from base64.

Comment: @YashRami Sure just a second.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this. I hope it helps

```
openGallery() {
const options: CameraOptions = {
 quality: 50,
 destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
 encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
 mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
 correctOrientation: true,
 sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
};
this.camera
 .getPicture(options)
 .then(imageData=> {
   let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData; //mimetype should be change based on image type
   this.upload(base64Image);
 }, err => console.log(err));
}

upload(file: any) {
  this.uploadService.uploadfile(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve using type binary on the request body:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://api_id.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stage/uploadpicture' \
--header 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' \
--data-binary '@a.jpg'
```

The issue was fixed by using the above command instead of:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://api_id.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/stage/uploadpicture' \
--header 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' \
--form 'image=@a.jpg'
```

Data binary(--data-binary parameter) instead of form(--form) did the trick.